# How to access fields of an object from an objectArray

Tags: reactjs

In my home component below, and on the console I get object array [console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTPzY.png).
I can't access the field from the object since it throws the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'medicineId' of undefined
> **when i try the peice of code below,**

```
{medlist &&
           medlist.map(({medicineId, medicineName }) => (
              <li  key={medicineId} >
               <h1>{medicineName}</h1>
              </li>               
            ))}
```

it gives me index.js:1 **Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.** even though the key is unique.but idk it gives me this unique key prop err cuz it is of type string.

Note that `medicineId` is of type string. and i tried to overcome this by changing that piece of code to,

```
{medlist &&
           medlist.map((med,idx) => (
              <li  key={idx} >
               <h1>{med.medicineName}</h1>
              </li>               
            ))}
```

**and now i dont get the warning for unique key but, there is no display of the  tag *med.medicineName*.**
when i tried {console.log(med.medicineName)}
it is **undefined**

```
    import React from 'react'
    const {useEffect,useState} = React;
    const axios = require('axios');
    
    
    const fetchMedicineList = () =>{
      
        return axios.get('http://localhost:8080/medicine')
        .then(({data})=>{
            console.log(data)
            return JSON.stringify(data);
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            console.error(err)
        });
    
        
    }
    
    
    function Home() {
        const [medlist, setMedlist] = useState([])
    
        useEffect(() => {
            fetchMedicineList().then(medicineList=>{
                setMedlist([...medlist,medicineList]);
            })
            
            // return () => {
                
            // }
        }, [medlist])
        return (
            <div>
     {medlist &&
                medlist.map(({med:{medicineId, medicineName }}) => (
                  <div className="card" key={medicineId} >
                   <h1>{medicineName}</h1>
                  </div>               
                ))}
            </div>
           
        )
    }
    
    export default Home
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems. The first is that you're returning `JSON.stringify(data)` from the `fetchMedicineList` function. `JSON.stringify` returns the JSON input as a string, see here:

```js
const data = {
  a: 1,
  b: 'another property',
  c: true
}

const medlist = [data];

console.log('JSON:', medlist);
console.log('JSON.stringify:', JSON.stringify(medlist));
const x = JSON.stringify(medlist);
console.log(x[0]);    // Prints '[' because it's the first character in the string
```

That means you're setting `medlist` to a string value. Instead, you just need to `return data;`

The second problem is your `map`. Instead, you should just do `medlist.map(({medicineId, medicineName}) => ...);`

```js
const data = {
  a: 1,
  b: 'another property',
  c:  true
};

const medlist = [data];

medlist.map(({a,b,c}) => console.log(a, b, c));
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with the way you're destructuring the `med` object. As you have it, the shape of each medicine object would look like `{med: {medicineId, medicineName}}`, but looks like they just have the shape `{medicineId, medicineName}` (without the `med` key).

You can update the `medlist.map(({med:{medicineId, medicineName }}) =>` line to:

```
medlist.map(({medicineId, medicineName }) =>
```